# Using function as an arrayformula to calculate each row's data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

What the function does is transpose a set row of ids and a changing row of quantities. In return the rows that have a quantity are returned with the id and the remaining array is used to query a pricing range. Finally the total price is summed for all the id's and their respective quantities. Also the final total price is multiplied by the corresponding row in CT.

Right now I have the function in every row in column CW4:CW as I cannot seem to get the arrayformula to calculate the data how I need it.

Spreadsheet (Hid unnecessary columns and pages):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5p0WPQg6F8ZlBDWpKrJKHoXIlfQOOYYs7491Mr-EIA/edit?usp=sharing

Future apologies if my explanation isn't the greatest, it's late here and I've spent a deal of time stuck on the problem. Feel free to comment if you need clarification or an example sheet.

Function:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFNA(
QUERY(
{VLOOKUP(QUERY({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(CX$3:EO$3 & " " & CX4:EO4), " ", 1, 0)}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL", 0), EP$4:ER, 3) *
QUERY({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(CX$3:EO$3 & " " & CX4:EO4), " ", 1, 0)}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL", 0)}, 
"SELECT sum(Col1) LABEL sum(Col1) ''", 0) / CT4, ""), ""
))
```

References I need to work as an array:

```
CX4:EO4
CT4
```

Pic of data:

[image: Sheet stuffs]

[image: another one]

Comment: Images aren't very helpful. The only way the volunteer contributors here can even begin to consider a solution is if you provide a link to your actual spreadsheet (or to a copy of it). Otherwise, you are expecting the volunteers to build their own sheet and manually type in your data first, before they can even start. And that will be a deterrent to getting  the kind of help your asking for. Help us help you: share a link.

Comment: Edited with the spreadsheet, hid the unneeded columns and pages for the data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MMULT(IFERROR(INDIRECT("I4:AZ"&MAX(ROW(A4:A)*(A4:A<>"")))*
 HLOOKUP(IF(INDIRECT("I4:AZ"&MAX(ROW(A4:A)*(A4:A<>"")))="",,I3:AZ3), 
 TRANSPOSE(BA:BC), 3, ), 0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(I:AZ), 1, 1, ))/E4:E))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZOZFN3GWaa6rp2Ce4ARUvX4yKfAMYRnsKMM7igbW3W0/edit#gid=1977173467)

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(MMULT(IFNA(INDIRECT("I4:AZ"&MAX(ROW(A4:A)*(A4:A<>"")))*
 VLOOKUP(IF(INDIRECT("I4:AZ"&MAX(ROW(A4:A)*(A4:A<>"")))="",,I3:AZ3), 
 BA:BC, 3, ), 0), FLATTEN(COLUMN(I:AZ))^0)/E4:E))
```

even more shorter but slow (not recommended to use):

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(MMULT(IFNA(I4:AZ*VLOOKUP(IF(I4:AZ="",,I3:AZ3), 
 BA:BC, 3, ), 0), FLATTEN(COLUMN(I:AZ))^0)/E4:E))
```